# Last character of text file is not retrieved with System.IO

Tags: c#, streamreader, outputstream, streamwriter, .net

I tried to write a text file using `OutputStream.Write` but, I've noticed that the last character of the file is not being sent.

Whether the file is 6KB or 242KB, the last character is skipped.

```
AwAIB0UfFlJTSTNABEQWGgMVAhNFBkVeKgVTSx4LCVQMBUUQRUMwBVFTGwcAEAASRRNTBipNQQMFDREYB
BUAH0VIKgVLRVccCRFFGRcbR08wREgDEQENEUkCDRNOTX5cS1ZXHgQGHFYIB0NOfgUIAwMABFQABBcdUg
YpRFcDHgZBAA0TRTEDBj1KQEZXREEdRRIKHFQGK0tARgUbFRULEkUFSF9+R1FXVxwJEUUkAAFQSTBWQQ0
xBBQHDV5MUkFIOgV2RgQYDhoWE0sxTEktQAwKVx8AB0UCDRcAQyxXS1FZSBUcBAIWUldDN1dAAxEHE1QI
E0UTTkJ+TARAFgYVVBAYARdSVSpESkdXAAAcBFg=
```

**Note**: *whole text is one line in the text file.*

My text file is somewhat similar to the above. So can anyone help me out?

### My code:

```
var path = Request.QueryString["path"];
path = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Files/" + path + "/somefile.txt"));
Response.Buffer = false;
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
int len = (int)file.Length, bytes;
Response.AppendHeader("content-length", len.ToString());
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
Stream outStream = Response.OutputStream;
using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
{
    while (len > 0 && (bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        outStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        len -= bytes;
    }
}
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

**UPDATE 1:**
*Now shows the complete text from the file.*

**UPDATE 2 :**
*Updated the complete C# code.*

**UPDATE 3:**
*Thanks, my friends, for all your efforts! I somehow made it work - the problem was `Response.Flush()` and `Response.Close()`; once I removed these 2 statements it started working. I don't understand why this problem occurred as I always use `Response.Flush()` and `Response.Close()`. I never received this kind of error but this was the first time. If anyone could give me an explanation, it would be appreciated. I will mark @AlexeiLevenkov's post as the answer, as I just tested it again without the `Response.Flush` and `Close()` and it is working.*

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps there's something 'iffy' about your file?

Comment: would you please check it once again with the above text ?? thanks

Comment: The stream processing itself appears to be ok, so I suspect something in the way that you are handling the web request/response.  A trace of the http requests/responses (header and body) might be helpful. You can capture those with a tool such as fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)

Comment: It might also be helpful to post any code that executes after your while loop, particularly if it deals with ``Response``.

Comment: @Nathan : i have updated the C# code, thats all i have in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.stream.copyto%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is easier approaach (as long as you can use .Net 4.0).

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
{
  stream.CopyTo(outStream);
}
```

Comment: my friend , i still have the problem .. i have edited my post , and now i am showing my whole text in the file. please test with that

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov : if i use the your code , then i am not getting the proper output , it is not even sending the the complete file , it just sends some 3/4 of the file thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `Response.Flush()` or `outStream.Flush()`

Comment: i am already calling FLUSH ... its just not written here for the post. sorry for that